# strange newlines being inserted in python file write

Tags: python, file, fwrite

Does anyone have any idea or know of any situation where python inserts newline characters strangely.

This is my piece of code

```
  if ((sentAnalyze) and len(OpString)!=0):
    if data[8]!= '':
        if (data[8] == 'p'):
            OpString = "1 " + OpString
        elif (data[8] == 'n'):
            OpString = "-1 " + OpString
        elif (data[8] == 'neu'):
            OpString = "0 " + OpString
        print "writing :", OpString
        fw.write(OpString + "\n")
```

When I try looking at the print commands and the file write commands, there is a an extra new line inserted in the file for certain line numbers.

this entire if block is in a while loop and the print command prints the lines properly.

and yeah I am opening the file in `w+` mode.

Function (partially written here) to compute the OpString

```
 for word,tag in simplified_tokens:
                tok = word + "/" + tag
                if tok in self.wordtoPosition:
                    OpString = OpString+ " " + str(self.wordtoPosition[tok]) + ":1" #+ str(1.0 / self.uniqPOSHash[tok])
return OpString
```

And the data looks like

```
1981:1 503:1 21:1 58:1 159:1 1:1 87:1 412:1 105:1 478:1 1154:1 1023:1 1192:1 53:1 37:1 36:1 598:1 19:1 4:1 162:1 14:1 131:1 2:1 489:1 411:1 3:1 165:1 370:1


-17:1 614:1 6:1 631:1 59:1 1:1 0:1 1183:1 10:1 22:1 15:1 67:1 55:1 3:1 175:1 9:1 43:1 866:1 48:1 30:1 0:1 484:1 2:1 1106:1 109:1
```

Notice the extra newline between. Only happening at certain places.

repr(OpString) shows

```
'1981:1 503:1 21:1 58:1 159:1 1:1 87:1 412:1 105:1 478:1 1154:1 1023:1 1192:1 53:1 37:1 36:1 598:1 19:1 4:1 162:1 14:1 131:1 2:1 489:1 411:1 3:1 165:1 370:1'
'-17:1 614:1 6:1 631:1 59:1 1:1 0:1 1183:1 10:1 22:1 15:1 67:1 55:1 3:1 175:1 9:1 43:1 866:1 48:1 30:1 0:1 484:1 2:1 1106:1 109:1'
```

Note. Removing "\n" will still add a line when I am writing to the file for certain lines. That is weird

Another Interesting Observation. In the above approach, I am reading from a file and writing into a different file. sO i have 2 file handles open. fr for file read and fw for file write. If I just have fr open, build the entire OpString variable, close fr and then write it using fw, I do not get weird new lines. Very interesting!

Comment: `print repr(OpString)` to inspect the value

Comment: use just `if data[8]:` instead of `if data[8]!= '':`

Comment: can you paste the content of the file or some more code?

Comment: @Gaurav please paste this in your post, not in comments & is this the input data?

Comment: @gaurav we need the input data.

Comment: Are you aware that your code -- at least as pasted here -- contains a mix of tabs and spaces? That could really cause problems with your block structure. You should make sure that's not the problem -- call your script with `python -tt myscript.py`.

Comment: Its the formatting with StackOverflow that it is being displayed without tabs. Its properly handled on my file. @senderle

Answer (score 3):

We'd really have to see the *input* data you are working with .. in the meantime, can you try

```
fw.write(Opstring.strip() + '\n')
```

`strip()` will strip any errand newlines you may have from the original data before appending the one explicitly for the `write`.

I suspect at least some of your `OpString`s have a trailing newline already.

This is not meant as a *fix*, but a *diagnostic*. Once you determine this is the source of the problem, then a better approach would be to eliminate the errand newlines at the origin/when you read them.

*Update*:

Better yet, do an

```
 Opstring = Opstring.strip()
```

before you enter the `if`-statement as per @kindall's helpful comment

Comment: treating a symptom is a bad approach in general. The OP should find out where the newlines are coming and eliminate the root cause.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I totally agree, this was not meant as a *fix* .. see the part where I say " .. in the meantime .." so this is meant as a diagnostic. Once we know that's the problem, the clearly the solution is to get rid of the newlines at the source.

Comment: If I was going to strip newlines here, I'd strip them before entering the `if`, not when writing to the file.

Comment: @kindall good point ... this was really just taking a first stab at it. If you won't mind I'll make the change you mention.

Comment: @Levon.  A better response would have been:  "I totally agree.  I've edited my answer to make that clear."  Your response makes it sound like J.F. Sebastion misread what you wrote, but what actually happened is that his feedback motivated you to update your answer.

Comment: @Gaurav in that case we really need to see your data.

Comment: This is the data that is being printed 1 981:1 503:1 21:1 58:1 159:1 1:1 87:1 412:1 105:1 478:1 1154:1 1023:1 1192:1 53:1 37:1 36:1 598:1 19:1 4:1 162:1 14:1 131:1 2:1 489:1 411:1 3:1 165:1 370:1
[newline]   : sorry cannot edit the same way as the original file. Notice the extra newline between
[newline]
-1 7:1 614:1 6:1 631:1 59:1 1:1 0:1 1183:1 10:1 22:1 15:1 67:1 55:1 3:1 175:1 9:1 43:1 866:1 48:1 30:1 0:1 484:1 2:1 1106:1 109:1

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I think my use of the phrase " .. in the meantime .. " was clear, and I agreed with JFSebastian, and yes, his post motivated me to improve my answer - please don't try to introduce quarell/disagreement where there is none.

Comment: @Gaurav We need the ***input*** data

Comment: Modified the quesion. see above

Comment: Do you still need more inputs?

Comment: input data is a string of text which I am tokenizing using PyML

Comment: Your input data has at least 4 newlines, how are you getting rid of them? Please try this `Opstring = Opstring.strip()` statement before your `if ((sentAnalyze)...`  and see if that makes a difference (the assignment *is* important)

Comment: Okay the function which is returning OpString is now returning it as OpString.strip(), so that should handle all the unneecessary newlines. But still I am getting the extra newlines. Is there any maximum size of the filelines to be written or is it because of the modein which I am opening the file.

Comment: See another observation posted in the question

Comment: I don't know when/where you call the function that gets OpString .. and it's hard to help diagnose your code if you don't follow suggested step. I suggested you put the code as close as you can to where you print it not somewhere else. At the moment I am out of suggestions. It's also a bit puzzling that your input data has some blank lines in it, which could be the source of your newlines as previously mentioned.

Comment: @levon thanks. Fixed this issue. The problem was with this line fw.write(OpString + "\n"). This was giving weird results. I assume, python gets confused whether to append to the string or the file or both in some cases. So I appended \n ouside this call and then called .write on OpString. It fixed the issue

Comment: I don't think that is the problem (I use this construct frequently myself) but if your problem has disappeared perhaps that's all that matters at this point, good luck.

Comment: No i am pretty sure that was the problem. After I changed  fw.write(OpString + "\n"). to OpString = Opstring + "\n" and fw.write(OpString), it disappeared. It was occuring only on certain lines (weird newlines being added). I think its a bug!